# Javascript to show sum = 0 when no item is present in the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have used the below JavaScript code to get the sum value of list column and the display it in a div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Effort");   
function Effort(){
var effortSpent = document.getElementById("aggrWPQ3").lastElementChild.innerText;
var IntEffortSpent = effortSpent.substring(4);
var results = parseInt(IntEffortSpent) + 0;

document.getElementById("DIV").innerHTML=results ;

    };
</script>
```

This code works when there is some item in the list and it is able to get the sum value and display it in the div but when there is no item in the list,I want it to display 0 in the same div.

what is needed to be done?

Comment: what does IntEffortSpent return when list is empty? get its value by console.log(IntEffortSpent);

Comment: effortSpent will be like sum=14(when item in list) and when no item in list it showed error when debugged in document.getElementById("aggrWPQ3").lastElementChild.innerText; line of code with red line under lastElementChild.innerText;

Comment: see my answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based you comment the solution should be

```
function Effort() {
    var results = 0;
    if (document.getElementById("aggrWPQ3")) {
        var effortSpent = document.getElementById("aggrWPQ3").lastElementChild.innerText;
        var IntEffortSpent = effortSpent.substring(4);
        results = parseInt(IntEffortSpent) + 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("DIV").innerHTML = results
};
```

I am assuming that document.getElementById("aggrWPQ3") is `undefined`. `document.getElementById("aggrWPQ3").lastElementChild` could be `undefined` also. In that case, solution should be

```
function Effort() {
    var results = 0;
    if (document.getElementById("aggrWPQ3").lastElementChild) {
        var effortSpent = document.getElementById("aggrWPQ3").lastElementChild.innerText;
        var IntEffortSpent = effortSpent.substring(4);
        results = parseInt(IntEffortSpent) + 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("DIV").innerHTML = results
};
```

Let me know which one has worked.